# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords, which log is deleted by this command?

Tags: sql-server

In MSSQL agent of syspolicy_purge_history, step 3 is EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords command to delete some logs. But I wonder if which log is deleted by this command exactly.

Could anyone let me know about this?

Comment: I have checked EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords method is to delete msdb.dbo.syspolicy_system_health_state table with health_state_id. But I still want to know what kind of record is deleted.

Comment: I inserted the record including server/database/tablename into the table and it was deleted after running the function. The record is made by mssql system like that.

Comment: It looks MSSQL makes the record to delete virtual records for specific table. But I wonder when the system makes the records...